# Azure cognitive services: Async Text analytics for PII, limiting max allowed char size to 5120 when it should be 125,000

Tags: azure, nlp, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api, azure-ai

I am using azure-ai-textanalytics(version 5.2.7) library for detecting PII in some text content that I have.
From the azure documentation the maximum chars allowed while using asynchronous processing is 125,000 chars.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/concepts/data-limits
[image]

Using the azure library below is how I am constructing the asynchronous client:

```
 private static TextAnalyticsAsyncClient createTextClient() {
        if (textAnalyticsClient == null) {
            textAnalyticsClient = new TextAnalyticsClientBuilder()
                    .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(AzureKeyVaultConnector.readKeyValue("languageResourceKey")))
                    .endpoint(AzureKeyVaultConnector.readKeyValue("languageResourceEndPoint"))
                    .buildAsyncClient();
        }
        return textAnalyticsClient;
    }
```

And I submit the documents to process using the below line:

```
 RecognizePiiEntitiesResultCollection piiEntityCollection = createTextClient().recognizePiiEntitiesBatch(documents,"en",requestOptions).block();
```

When I test with a string which is around 7000 chars, I get below error:

```
A document within the request was too large to be processed. Limit document size to: 5120 text elements. For additional details on the data limitations see https://aka.ms/text-analytics-data-limits
```

Why is it still trying to limit my max char size allowed to 5120? Shouldn't it be 125,000 since I am using async client? Any help is appreciated.

I would love to use azure-ai-textanalytics library and achieve this and not make direct http calls (Without using azure library).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the scenario you have given, I have reproduced the code and output using [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-ai-textanalytics_5.3.0b2/sdk/textanalytics/azure-ai-textanalytics/samples/async_samples/sample_recognize_pii_entities_async.py) sample async request code provided in [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ai-textanalytics-readme?preserve-view=true&view=azure-python-preview#multiple-analysis)

The issue you're encountering is because the 125,000 character limit is for the total number of characters across all submitted documents in an asynchronous request, not for a single document.
The maximum characters allowed for a single document in asynchronous processing is still **5,120 characters** .

For PII detection you can request limit is **5 Documents** as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/concepts/data-limits) shared by you.
So, for PII detection the total number of character limit per request is : **25600**

For example, if your request contain 2 documents (5120 characters ) and 3 documents ()
The output will produce results for 2 documents (Length under limit).

Output: https://i.imgur.com/OUmrwvk.png

All 5 documents must be under 5120 character limit to get complete result.

**To process a larger document (larger then 5120 characters), you can break it into smaller chunks of text before sending them to the API.**
Below is a  sample code snippet to create list of documents with single larger document/Text:

In Python,

```py
 def  split_string(string):
 #Splits a string into multiple strings, each of which is no more than 5120 characters long.
 strings = []
 for  i  in  range(0, len(string), 5120):
     strings.append(string[i:min(len(string), i + 5120)]) 
 return  strings
```

In Java,

```java
// Split the string into multiple strings, each of which is no more than 5120 characters long. 
List<String> strings = new List<String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i += 5120) { 
strings.add(originalString.substring(i, Math.min(originalString.length(), i + 5120))); }
```

Comment: Thank you @RishabhM.
I am confused because if I use direct http calls(following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/language/2022-05-01/text-analysis-runtime/submit-job?tabs=HTTP#piitaskparameters) to REST endpoint : https://ResourceName.cognitiveservices.azure.com/language/analyze-text/jobs/d18d1d1f-d3b9-493c-a214-f6bd5030edf8?api-version=2022-05-01   (followed by GET call to get job results), with the same document it extracts PII and gives me results.

I am looking for a way to use the azure-ai-textanalytics library and not have HTTP calls directly in my implementation.

Comment: I had considered splitting the document as well, but the thought of split happening exactly on PII data is scary. Even though I make sure that the split happens only after a complete word, if the split happens between 'firstname lastname' for example(or address), I will loose meaningful data. I tested this and extracted information on split documents was not satisfactory(When address was split, the model did not recognize it as address at all).

Comment: I understand you concern but based on your scenario, splitting is the way to go if you want to use azure-ai-textanalytics library.
You can try various methods such as sentence boundary detection to maintain the context.